# ParagraphFormat() with numbers

Tags: coldfusion, member-functions, coldfusion-2016

Apparently not all numbers have the same member functions in ColdFusion 2016

```
<cfset NumberString = 1>    

<!--- This works --->
<cfoutput>#NumberString.paragraphFormat()#</cfoutput>   

<cfset mystring = "Hello World ">

<cfset NumberString = mystring.len()>   
<!--- This crashes --->
<cftry>
    <cfoutput>#NumberString.paragraphFormat()#</cfoutput>   
    <cfcatch><cfdump var="#cfcatch#"></cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

[image]

Comment: Bug submitted: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198258

Comment: (Edit) Probably because the second variable is not really a String. `Len()` returns an Integer. Force it to be a string by casting, prepending an empty string, `""& myString.len()`, etcetera and it will work as expected.

Comment: That solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epilogue

Adobe won't be fixing this in CF-4198258

Leigh's workaround is the solution

```
<cfset NumberString = "" & mystring.len()>  

<cfoutput>#NumberString.paragraphFormat()#</cfoutput>
```